# Wait for jQuery animation to complete without using the callback

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

I have the following structure

```
$('foo').click( function() {
    var bool = false;
    $('bar').animate( function() {
        //bool = something
    });

    return bool;
});
```

But because the animation callback is async, bool is never set properly. Moving the return statement into the callback doesn't make sense. How can I get the return statement to wait until the animation completes?

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do? We can suggest an alternate approach if you could provide some background.

Comment: "Moving the return statement into the callback doesn't make sense." Why not?

Comment: @j08691 - because that returns for the anonymous function, not for the parent function

Comment: @Vega - `foo` is like a submit button. `bar` is an animation to hide some stuff, in the callback I do some form revalidation. Finally I return true/false to determine whether I should progress.

Comment: @mrtsherman I would suggest to prevent default submit, animate/validate then inside the callback do the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible, the return will happen immediately—there is no way to delay it. Try doing it this way instead:

```
$('foo').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = this;
    $('bar').animate( function() {
        if (somecondition) {
            window.location.href = _this.href;
            // or submit the form, etc.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Bummer man. I wish I had asked on SO before banging my head on my desk.

Answer (score 2):

Try like below,

```
$('foo').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent submission

    var bool = false;
    $('bar').animate( function() {
        //bool = something
        if (bool) { 
           //do what you wanted to do
        }
    });   
});
```